# Regex: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which I want to extract a subset of. This is part of a larger Python script.

This is the string:

```
import re

htmlString = '</dd><dt> Fine, thank you.&#160;</dt><dd> Molt bé, gràcies. (<i>mohl behh, GRAH-syuhs</i>)'
```

Which I want to pull-out "*Molt bé, gràcies. mohl behh, GRAH-syuhs*". And for that I use regular expression using `re.search`:

```
SearchStr = '(\<\/dd\>\<dt\>)+ ([\w+\,\.\s]+)([\&\#\d\;]+)(\<\/dt\>\<dd\>)+ ([\w\,\s\w\s\w\?\!\.]+) (\(\<i\>)([\w\s\,\-]+)(\<\/i\>\))'

Result = re.search(SearchStr, htmlString)

print Result.groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Since `Result.groups()` doesn't work, neither do the extractions I want to make (i.e. `Result.group(5)` and `Result.group(7)`).
But I don't understand why I get this error? The regular expression works in TextWrangler, why not in Python? Im a beginner in Python.

Comment: try decoding your `htmlString` into Unicode

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import re

htmlString = '</dd><dt> Fine, thank you.&#160;</dt><dd> Molt bé, gràcies. (<i>mohl behh, GRAH-syuhs</i>)'

SearchStr = '(\<\/dd\>\<dt\>)+ ([\w+\,\.\s]+)([\&\#\d\;]+)(\<\/dt\>\<dd\>)+ ([\w\,\s\w\s\w\?\!\.]+) (\(\<i\>)([\w\s\,\-]+)(\<\/i\>\))'

Result = re.search(SearchStr.decode('utf-8'), htmlString.decode('utf-8'), re.I | re.U)

print Result.groups()
```

Works that way. The expression contains non-latin characters, so it usually fails. You've got to decode into Unicode and use re.U (Unicode) flag.

I'm a beginner too and I faced that issue a couple of times myself.

Answer (score 61):

You are getting `AttributeError` because you're calling `groups` on `None`, which hasn't any methods.

`regex.search` returning `None` means the regex couldn't find anything matching the pattern from supplied string.

when using regex, it is nice to check whether a match has been made:

```
Result = re.search(SearchStr, htmlString)

if Result:
    print Result.groups()
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with escaping the () in (<i>mohl behh, GRAH-syuhs</i>). I have tried both '\(' and '\\(' but neither seem to work.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize all I needed was `if Result:`... Why does that statement work? When reading it, it just feels like it's missing the rest of the if statement.

Comment: because it compares the object != None i think. and if that statement is true you enter the if part

Comment: @Fumbles - It's worth reading about ["truthy and falsy" values in Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/). You can do lots of cool tricks with if statements - like if you want to test whether a list is empty or not, just do `if my_list:`, and it will run only if the list is non-empty. Empty lists, empty strings, the integer 0, or in this case empty regex matches, all are considered "Falsy", so they fail truth tests in conditionals.