# Not able to create a good regular expression for mod-security analysis

Tags: python, regex, mod-security

Not able to create a good regular expression for capturing complete data between `--c5eda821-H-` and `--c5eda821-Z-`

My regex for this query is

```
re.compile('--([a-f0-9]{8})-H-(.+?)--[a-f0-9]{8}', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

--c5eda821-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Length: 1567
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

--c5eda821-E--

--c5eda821-H--
Message: Warning. String match "0" at RESPONSE_HEADERS:X-XSS-Protection. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "141"] [id "981403"] [msg "AppDefect: IE8's XSS protection Filter is Disabled."] [data "X-XSS-Protection: 0"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag "http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checks#internet-explorer-xss-filter-disabled"]
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1501247328871413 10305 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1501247328871413 10305; combined=2942, p1=395, p2=2280, p3=34, p4=41, p5=147, sr=108, sw=45, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.8.
Server: Apache
WebApp-Info: "default" "59EFAF5D261B7D5BE14460C1BF3EE0A9" ""
Engine-Mode: "DETECTION_ONLY"

--c5eda821-Z--
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am getting an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

Comment: A possible dup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232832/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-groups

Comment: @revo I tried that din't work facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> haystack = """--c5eda821-H-

Message: Warning. Match of "eq 1" against "&ARGS:CSRF_TOKEN" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf"] [line "31"] [id "981143"] [msg "CSRF Attack Detected - Missing CSRF Token."]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "(.*?)=(?i)(?!.*httponly.*)(.*$)" at RESPONSE_HEADERS:Set-Cookie. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "83"] [id "981184"] [msg "AppDefect: Missing HttpOnly Cookie Flag for auth."] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag "http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checks#cookie-not-setting-httponly-flag"]
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1501247328778702 7722 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1501247328778702 7722; combined=2901, p1=886, p2=1609, p3=54, p4=87, p5=213, sr=309, sw=52, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); 
OWASP_CRS/2.2.8.
Server: Apache
WebApp-Info: "default" "59EFAF5D261B7D5BE14460C1BF3EE0A9" ""
Engine-Mode: "DETECTION_ONLY"


--c5eda821-Z--"""

>>> print(re.search(r'--[\da-e]{8}-\w-(.+?)--[\da-e]{8}-\w--$', haystack, re.M|re.DOTALL).group(1))


Message: Warning. Match of "eq 1" against "&ARGS:CSRF_TOKEN" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf"] [line "31"] [id "981143"] [msg "CSRF Attack Detected - Missing CSRF Token."]
Message: Warning. Pattern match "(.*?)=(?i)(?!.*httponly.*)(.*$)" at RESPONSE_HEADERS:Set-Cookie. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "83"] [id "981184"] [msg "AppDefect: Missing HttpOnly Cookie Flag for auth."] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag 
"http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checks#cookie-not-setting-httponly-flag"]
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1501247328778702 7722 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1501247328778702 7722; combined=2901, p1=886, p2=1609, p3=54, p4=87, p5=213, sr=309, sw=52, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); 
OWASP_CRS/2.2.8.
Server: Apache
WebApp-Info: "default" "59EFAF5D261B7D5BE14460C1BF3EE0A9" ""
Engine-Mode: "DETECTION_ONLY"
```

The error message you describe is because when there is no match, `re.search` returns `None`, and `None` has no `groups` attribute.

I order to prevent this exception, you should test the return value from the method in order to check if there is any match:

```
regex = re.compile(r'--[\da-e]{8}-\w-(.+?)--[\da-e]{8}-\w--$', re.M|re.DOTALL)
match = regex.search(haystack)
if match:
    print match.group(1)
else:
    print "No match"
```

[UPDATE]

> Yeah you are right in case of one only long string, I have many more in the same fashion. But, i only want the content between those tags. – dumbo

Try this:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'--[\da-e]{8}-\w--(.+?)--[\da-e]{8}-\w--', re.M|re.DOTALL)

>>> for i, match in enumerate(regex.findall(haystack)):
...     print('{:02d}-> {}...'.format(i, match[:15].strip()))     

00-> HTTP/1.1 200 O...
01-> Message: Warni...
```

The `findall` method will return a list of matches. If you want only the last match:

```
>>> matches = regex.findall(haystack)

>>> print(matches[-1])
```

Or just the second one:

```
>>> print(matches[1])
```

Comment: Yeah you are right in case of one only long string, I have many more in the same fashion. But, i only want the content between those tags.

Comment: Ok, see if the updated answer is what you want. If not, please be more specific. For example, it is always "H" and "Z"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two re.sub calls to eliminate the parts you don't want. If this works in your situation the regex expressions are often simpler.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = open('temp.txt').read()
>>> re.sub(r'--c5eda821-Z--', '', re.sub(r'--c5eda821-H-', '', text))
'\n\nMessage: Warning. Match of "eq 1" against "&ARGS:CSRF_TOKEN" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf"] [line "31"] [id "981143"] [msg "CSRF Attack Detected - Missing CSRF Token."]\nMessage: Warning. Pattern match "(.*?)=(?i)(?!.*httponly.*)(.*$)" at RESPONSE_HEADERS:Set-Cookie. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "83"] [id "981184"] [msg "AppDefect: Missing HttpOnly Cookie Flag for auth."] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag "http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checks#cookie-not-setting-httponly-flag"]\nApache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php\nStopwatch: 1501247328778702 7722 (- - -)\nStopwatch2: 1501247328778702 7722; combined=2901, p1=886, p2=1609, p3=54, p4=87, p5=213, sr=309, sw=52, l=0, gc=0\nResponse-Body-Transformed: Dechunked\nProducer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.8.\nServer: Apache\nWebApp-Info: "default" "59EFAF5D261B7D5BE14460C1BF3EE0A9" ""\nEngine-Mode: "DETECTION_ONLY"\n\n\n'
```

Edit in response to comment: then I suggest an approach like this.

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('temp.txt') as text:
...     for line in text.readlines():
...         if re.match(r'--c5[a-z]{3}821-[A-Z]-', line.strip()):
...             continue
...         else:
...             print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Sorry for the misconception, there are many ids --c5eda821-Z- with different tags at end