# During activating Tensorflow program, Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. How can I solve this?

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, tensorflow

When I was using Tensorflow to follow the tutorial of Simple Audio Recognition on TensorFlow page, I got a problem in downloading audio data for train.

I have entered the following command:

```
C:\Users\user\Document\Tensorflow\tensorflow\examples\speech_commands\train.py
```

and got an error message,

```
 Downloading speech_commands_v0.01.tar.gz 100.0%
INFO:tensorflow:Successfully downloaded speech_commands_v0.01.tar.gz (1488293908 bytes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Document\Tensorflow\tensorflow\examples\speech_commands\train.py", line 427, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 133, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\user\Document\Tensorflow\tensorflow\examples\speech_commands\train.py", line 104, in main
    FLAGS.testing_percentage, model_settings)
  File "C:\Users\user\Document\Tensorflow\tensorflow\examples\speech_commands\input_data.py", line 161, in __init__
    testing_percentage)
  File "C:\Users\user\Document\Tensorflow\tensorflow\examples\speech_commands\input_data.py", line 243, in prepare_data_index
    word = re.search('.*/([^/]+)/.*.wav', wav_path).group(1).lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Should I fix the code on file input_data.py? If it is possible, how can I fix it? It will be helpful if anyone gives me some advice on this problem.

Comment: From the traceback that you have provided, the regex `'.*/([^/]+)/.*.wav'` does not match with the string `wav_path`. For more details see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232832/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-groups

Comment: could you please format your code so it is more readable please?

Comment: this is hard to answer without seeing the `train.py` file. Still posted an answer that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that your `re.search()` call returned `None`, hence the `AttributeError` you are getting.

I suggest you give a better look to your regexp to check that is what you desire. Another thing that I noted is that you are also calling `group(1)`. Make sure that is also the [group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) you wish to obtain with that regexp (and not `group(0)`). Alternatively, the `groups()` method will return all the subgroups of your match. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'a python error instead of a tensorflow error.

There's no match for your regexp in `re.search()`