# Getting 'AttributeError' on all regex tests except the last one

Tags: python, regex

My code is supposed to run through each line of a file and perform an action. The file looks like that:
`FIREFOX::https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ogame-fleet-counter/::<dd class=\"MetadataCard-content\">(.*?)<\/dd>`

There are 3 things in each line: **Name**::**URL**::**Regex**.

The code runs good with 1 line in the file, but more than that and the code only works with the last line, the others before just throw an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

I tried using other methods to run through the file, as I thought the error was there, but apparently it's not the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import urllib2
import sys

with open("addons.cfg", "r") as addons:
    for line in addons:
        try:
            name, url, regex = line.split("::")
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            page_source = response.read()

            m = re.search(regex, page_source)
            if m:
                print(m.group(1))
            else:
                print("Couldn't find!")
        except:
            print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
            raise
```

Video to show better the error: https://youtu.be/j_lwnlrj-fg

Comment: Can you show what do you receive in `page_source`?

Comment: @AmiHollander https://pastebin.com/nmaGyrUs

Comment: This is so close to a duplicate of [Python + Regex: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232832/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-groups) that I'd be amazed if you can't find a solution to your problem in this Q&A. :-)

Comment: @SimonShine My code works, but only runs the code on the last line of the file, if I have 2/3/4 lines only works with the last one. But I tried to decode into Unicode, still doesn't work.

Comment: You have way too much code in your try block, but anyway: the code you posted can NOT raise this error.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It raises that error, otherwise I wouldn't be posting here. Did you tried to recreate it?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you please take a look at the video? https://youtu.be/j_lwnlrj-fg I show the error there

Comment: @MiltonCardoso I'm certainly not going to watch a youtube video to read an error traceback, and I am 200% positive that the exact snippet you posted can NOT raise this error since in this snippet you only try to access `m.group` if `m` is not none. You are wasting everyone's time by not posting a MCVE and the full matching traceback.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm sorry, I expressed myself wrong. With the `if` It doesn't raise that, but without it, yes. So my problem was that when I split the line, the pattern for the regex had an extra `ENTER` on the end. I had to `strip()` the pattern before using it.

Comment: Of course it raises an AttributeError without the `if m:` test - `re.search()` returns `None` if nothing matches, and this is documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake, I had to use `regex.strip()` :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import urllib2
import sys

with open("addons.cfg", "r") as addons:
    for line in addons:
        name, url, regex = line.split("::")
        source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        regex = regex.strip()
        try:
            regex_result = re.search(regex, source)
            if regex_result:
                print(regex_result.group(1))
            else:
                print("error")
        except:
            print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
            raise
```