# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' , group doesn't return none

Tags: regex

I am facing an issue with regular expression, I went though many similar issues posted and found the mentioned answers was related to the groups on None or retuning none.

```
import re
route={}
gig_pattern = re.compile('(GigabitEthernet)([0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9])')
with open('ip-routes.txt','r')as f:
 for line in f:
   match = gig_pattern.search( line ) # Match for Gigabit Ethernet
   intf=match.group(2)
   route[inft]=route[intf]+1 if intf in route else 1
```

but if I print the variable(match) I can see a result of the regular expression which means it doesn't returning non, it is returning the expected pattern

<re.Match object; span=(49, 71), match='GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1'>

Comment: But there is another line in the file where there is no match.

Comment: Duplicate of [Regex: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232832/python-regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-groups)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232832/regex-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-groups)

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed by modifying code as bellow

```
import re
route={}

gig_pattern = re.compile('(GigabitEthernet)([0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9]\/[0-9])')
with open('ip-routes.txt','r')as f:
 for line in f:
   match = gig_pattern.search( line ) # Match for Gigabit Ethernet
   if match is not None:
    intf = match.group(2)
    route[intf]=route[intf]+1 if intf in route else 1
```